# Abstract word embeddings with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I am new to TikZ and I am looking to draw simple abstraction of word embeddings.

Here's a quick sketch from Keynote:
[image]

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Have you attempted anything so far? If so please post what you have.

Comment: How long is the `sentence with some words`? Will it go beyond one line?

Comment: The sentence will be short, so one line. I haven't implemented it yet, but I think @john's answer below will work. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of ways one can go with this.  One could insert `\tikzmark` into regular text and overlay the arrows.  One could put each word into a separate `\tikz[remember picture]{node(name){...};}` and overlay the arrows from the `south` anchor.

This approach put everything into one `tikzpicture` with the entire sentence in one node.  The arrow ends are specified relative to the node anchors using the `calc` library notation.  The weird doohicky was specified as a pic to make it easy to reproduce.  Unlike nodes, pics don't have anchors.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows.meta}

\tikzset{doohicky/.pic={%
\fill[color=Aqua,rounded corners] (-15pt,-11pt) rectangle (15pt,-1pt);
\fill[color=yellow] (-10pt,-6pt) circle[radius=4pt]
                    (0pt,-6pt) circle[radius=4pt]
                    (10pt,-6pt) circle[radius=4pt];
}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (A) {Sentence with some words};
\draw[-latex] ($(A.south west)!.2!(A.south east)$) -- ++(-20pt,-20pt) pic{doohicky};
\draw[-latex] ($(A.south west)!.45!(A.south east)$) -- ++(-7.5pt,-20pt) pic{doohicky};
\draw[-latex] ($(A.south west)!.65!(A.south east)$) -- ++(7.5pt,-20pt) pic{doohicky};
\draw[-latex] ($(A.south west)!.9!(A.south east)$) -- ++(20pt,-20pt) pic{doohicky};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: weird doohickies]

Note, it is generally easier to debug a pic as a regular `tikzpicture`, then copy the code into the `\tikzset`.